# How to validate an xml file in ant?

Tags: ant

this is my xml file
   `<contacts>`
`<contact>`
`<firstname>Edwin</firstname>`
`<lastname>Dankert</lastname>`
`</contact>`
`</contacts>`

i want to validate it in ant,my target is

```
<target name="WellFormed">
<xmlvalidate file="contacts.xml"/>
<echo>WELL FORMED</echo>
</target>
```

C:\work\build\XML_VALIDATION>ant
Buildfile: C:\work\build\XML_VALIDATION\build.xml

<==========================ANT OUTPUT=============================>

```
WellFormed:
[xmlvalidate] contacts.xml:1:11: Document root element "contacts", must match DOCTYPE root "null".

[xmlvalidate] contacts.xml:1:11: Document is invalid: no grammar found.

BUILD FAILED
C:\work\build\XML_VALIDATION\build.xml:4: C:\work\build\XML_VALIDATION\contacts.xml is not a valid XML document.
```

i am not checking it against any xsd,can anyone help me in finding what changes i need to insert into the xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to make sure your XML is well-formed, then add the `lenient` attribute to your [xmlvalidate](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/xmlvalidate.html) task as follows.

```
<xmlvalidate file="contacts.xml" lenient="yes"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your build file is not valid, you need to start with

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="name">
<target name="target-name">
...
</target>
</project>
```

A google search for sample Ant build file will provide all you need to understand build files. This [link](http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html) will help too.

Comment: That i know,i have intentionally skipped the project name and other things,because they are mandatory....i have shown only that target which does the work